# Writing a search-with-suggestions field. Javascript focus problem

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dhtml

So I'm scripting up a search field for my website. As the user types, a box appears below the field with search suggestions. The suggestions are keyboard navigable and clickable.

However, I'm having trouble getting the suggestions to disappear when the user click's elsewhere on the page. I've added an onBlur() handler to the search field, but when the user clicks on one of the suggestions, the blur happens before the click, thus making the suggestions box disappear and the click event happens in dead space instead of on the suggestion.

Here's what my HTML looks like:

```
<input type="text" id="search_field" onBlur="hideSuggestions()" />
<div id="suggestions_box">
  <ul>
    <li onClick="doSomething(1)">suggestion1</li>
    <li onClick="doSomething(2)">suggestion2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So the question is, how can I hide the suggestions_box element when the focus leaves the search field, *except* when the new element with focus is the suggestions box?

Answer (score 1):

Keep your suggestions box div inside your form tag, then put the onBlur on the form.

```
<form id="myform" onBlur="hideSuggestions()" >
    <input type="text" id="search_field" />
    <div id="suggestions_box">
        <ul>
          <li onClick="doSomething(1)">suggestion1</li>
          <li onClick="doSomething(2)">suggestion2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </form>
```

[edit] I'm thinking this will work, but can't test it right now. The javascript reference over at w3schools says that form tag supports onblur, but I don't know if that means it has to be on a form element, or just within the form tag.[/edit]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

First make sure you pass the `blur` event to your `hideSuggestions` function:

```
<input type="text" id="search_field" onblur="hideSuggestions(event)" />
```

Next, check if the blur was caused by an event inside the suggestions box:

```
function hideSuggestions(event) {
    var target = event.relatedTarget || event.toElement,
        suggestions = document.getElementById('suggestions_box');

    if (contains(suggestions, target))
        // user did something inside suggestions box.
        return; // Do nothing.

    // box hiding code as before...
}

// contains(haystack, needle): fast lookup of whether haystack is a parent of needle.
var contains = document.compareDocumentPosition
             ? function(a, b) { return !!(a.compareDocumentPosition(b) & 16) }
             : function(a, b) { return a !== b && (a.contains ? a.contains(b) : true) };
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the right solution in general, but I'm using jquery, which doesn't correctly set the relatedTarget property (it's always undefined). Any workaround ideas?

Comment: I believe jQuery populates `relatedTarget` in general. However I don't know enough about the `blur` event and how jQuery interprets the `toElement` in IE. That may be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and come across this question. I'm using jQuery too and mouseout seems to be the only event having relatedTarget. In fact, probably none of the current browsers supports this (just checked Firefox 4 and IE 9).

I solved this by using mousedown on the document. I have a variable indicating an ongoing search. If a mousedown occurs in this state I just check if the clicked target has a certain class, that is only used to pick a suggestion. In any other case the suggestions get hidden.

event.target is a jQuery-element where you can look for all kind of stuff like nodeName, id and className.

```
$(document).mousedown(function(event) {
if (ongoingSearch) {
    if (event.target.className != "uniqueClassname") {
        hideSuggestions();
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use css. No java script is required.

The css will be like following.

```
#search_field:focus+#search_box
{
     display:block;
}
#search_box
{
     display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <input type="text" id="search_field" onBlur="hideSuggestions()" />
    <div id="suggestions_box">
      <ul>
        <li onClick="doSomething(1)">suggestion1</li>
        <li onClick="doSomething(2)">suggestion2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

You can use the onclick on the body element, then check the display of the suggestion for proper processing.

```
$('body').click(function(e){
   if($('.suggestions_box>ul').is(':visible')) $('.suggestions_box>ul').hide();
})
```

I have an example for you to refer to here([doc truyen](http://doc-truyen.vaoday.net)) hope it will help you